# SUMIF every other cell according to a criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying add every other cell if it means a certain criteria. I can add every other cell and SUMIF separately, but for the life of me I can't get to the two to work.

**Every other** :

> SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(A2:I2)),A2:I2)))

**SUMIF** :

> SUMIF(A1:H1,"s",A2:H2)

**Together:**

> =SUMIFS((ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(A2:I2)),A2:I2))),(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(A1:I1)),A1:I1))),"s")

[image]

[HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhSEZIbY5jX2M5HhCXdAI687Fwh2LPZ2_VDYa9Ok4Q0/edit#gid=0) is the simplified version of the document I am working with. I want to sum all blue cells that have an "s" in the row above

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS() function instead.

In your case:

```
=SUMIFS(A2:H2,A1:H1,"=s")
```

Details here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: Tried that with the formula from every other, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to switch to `SUMPRODUCT`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(A1:H1="s"),0+ISODD(COLUMN(A2:H2)),A2:H2)`

Apologies - I'm not sure if this will work in Google Sheets as it stands.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! It works in my test doc! Now to try it out in the real thing!